# Convert dict into String and then split specific portion of string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

1) I have input string, separated by commas, which server as keys. There is a userDefined method, which converts those comma separated strings into keys and also fills up with value in dict.

````
```
input_string=("'123','456'")
#userdefined method, which returns 
a_dict=convertIntoDict(input_string)

print (type (a_dict))
<type 'dict'>
```
````

Values of above dict are as follow:

```
print a_dict
{'123': <Merc:/Tire/Merc/aus>, '456': <Honda:/Tire/Honda/ind>}
```

I want to loop through the dict , and need output string without quotes and comma separated, such as
    output:

````
```Merc/aus, Honda/ind``` 

for ind_values in a_dict.values():
    s_i=str(ind_values)
    test_s=s_i.split("Instruments/", 1)[1].split(">",1)[0]
    print("attempt 1")
    print(test_s+",")
    test_f +=test_s+","
````

I want to loop through the dict , and need output string without quotes and comma separated, such as
    output:

```
Merc/aus, Honda/ind
```

Instead, it is showing the following,

```
Merc/aus, 
Honda/ind
```

Answer (score 0):

Change print(test_s+",") to print(test_s, end=", ")

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly code below should work.

```
a_dict = {'123': '<Merc:/Tire/Merc/aus>', '456': '<Honda:/Tire/Honda/ind>'}

result = list()

for ind_values in a_dict.values():
    s_i=str(ind_values)
    item = s_i.split("Tire")[1][:-1]
    result.append(item)

print(", ".join(result))
```

It produces following output:

```
 /Merc/aus, /Honda/ind
```